# Firing functions when commands are typed in textarea tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have this basic chat loaded up, built with jQuery and php (not by me) and I have changed it a little. Just to fit my purpose. Text is put in a textarea tag and then sent. I would like to have secret commands where you type a phrase and it does cool stuff. Such as typing "red" will make your name red. (I have already made script for this, just need to run it when somebody types red). What would I need to allow this?
Chat: https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet below gives an example of how you can accomplish this task. You leverage `textarea`'s `oninput` attribute to bind a function that looks at the contents of the text area. You can then do whatever you want with this, like calling your `red` function when the text is `red`.

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" oninput="onInput()"></textarea>

<script>
let ta = document.querySelector('#ta')
function onInput() {
  console.log(ta.value) // You can do stuff with this value
  if (ta.value === 'red') {
    applyRed()
  }
}
function applyRed() {
  ta.classList.add('red')
}
</script>
```